# Regex to capture string between string into array in js

Tags: javascript, regex

If we have the following string:

`"hukhkhk\nClosing Date: Friday 22nd April 2022\nwdwqdwqdwqd\nClosing Date: Friday 22nd April 2023\newdewfewf"`

and we want to get the 2 dates from it `"Friday 22nd April 2022"` and `"Friday 22nd April 2023"`

how do I go about getting an array back of all captured strings using js.

`[ "Friday 22nd April 2022", "Friday 22nd April 2023" ]`

There is an issue in my regex but not sure how to fix it so that it doesn't match everything in between the first `\n` it finds:

`(?<=Closing Date:\s)(.*)(?=\\n)`

https://regexr.com/6k2uf

The js I tried is this:

```js
var reg = new RegExp('(?<=Closing Date: )(.*)(?=\\n)/g');
reg.exec("hukhkhk\nClosing Date: Friday 22nd April 2022\nwdwqdwqdwqd\nClosing Date: Friday 22nd April 2023\newdewfewf")
```

Comment: `"\n"` is not a two char text. It is a line feed char, LF. So, when testing outside of code, use a line break, not `\n` text. Never throw in string literals where literal text is supposed to be. And just remove the `(?=\\n)` and use a regex literal. `var reg = /(?<=Closing Date: ).+/`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach for your example data, and any data with an easily definable marker for the required text, would be to `split` the data into an array of lines (demarked at `\n`), apply an array `filter` to the array to remove elements not containing the marker string, and finally `.map` the array to contain just the required part following the marker string.

The processes can be strung together in a single line as demonstrated in the following snippet:

```js
string = "hukhkhk\nClosing Date: Friday 22nd April 2022\nwdwqdwqdwqd\nClosing Date: Friday 22nd April 2023\newdewfewf";

markerString = "Closing Date: ";

datesArray = string.split('\n').filter(text => text.indexOf(markerString) > -1).map(text => text.slice(text.indexOf(markerString)+ markerString.length));

console.log(datesArray)
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=Closing Date: )(.*?)(?=\\n)`

Starts matching **after** `Closing Date:`  (space included)

Stops matching **before** the first `\n` it encounters

This worked on your example

[live example](https://regexr.com/6k2vs)

Comment: Arghhhh, the regex thing wasn't updating correctly on its grouping. Thanks Hein.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit:

1. I had to remove `group names` (were unused and making a breaking difference on runtime)
2. filtering empty strings (@input edges) as a result of `split()`

```
const input = "hukhkhk\\nClosing Date: Friday 22nd April 2022\\nwdwqdwqdwqd\\nClosing Date: Friday 22nd April 2023\\newdewfewf";
const regex = /(?:(?:\\n|^).*?(?:\\n|$))(?:Closing\sDate:\s)?/mg
const dates = input.split(regex).filter(date => date.length > 0);
console.log(dates);
```

Out:

```
[ 'Friday 22nd April 2022', 'Friday 22nd April 2023' ]
```

## 1st answer:

Using [regex](https://regex101.com/r/bhFNM1/1) to find all non-date content:

```js
const re = /(?<junk>(?:\\n|^).*?(?:\\n|$))(?<delimiter>Closing Date: )?/gm
```

Then using JS split to get array with dates only

```js
const dates = input.split(re);
```

Comment: Thank you. This one actually doesn't quite return only dates, but it's a good basis.

Comment: Apparently, here is some difference between .replace() and .split()
If I remove named-captured-groups names it will work with split.
will update my answer.